# Ubuntu 23.04 created me (inexplicably) 2 users

Tags: bug-reporting

i have a question. I upgraded Ubuntu from 22.10 to 23.04 (via software updater). Today, while I was doing some operations on the terminal (nothing relevant) I notice that the OS has created two profiles, here's what I got:

```
$ users
username username

$ who
username seat0        2023-04-29 17:17 (login screen)
username tty2         2023-04-29 17:17 (tty2)

$ w
 17:17:35 up 1 min,  2 users,  load average: 3,57, 1,28, 0,46
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
username seat0    login-           17:17    0.00s  0.00s   ?    /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bi
username tty2     tty2             17:17    1:04   0.04s  0.04s /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu
```

originally, when i was at version 22.10, i had only one user, but now i have two: why did this happen? How can I solve the problem?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Looks to me like you don't have two user names, you're logged in twice. Once on the console (tty2) and once in the gui, hence the gdm-wayland login manager running under your name.